# move element to cursor position on click in a html file using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

**i want to move a div to the current position of the mouse cursor on click using jquery**

I have a function that triggers whenever a mouse click event is performed on any part of the document, which works.

However, sending the position to my function doesn't work:

[Here's the jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/acharyarupak391/bghL6ad3/8/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    var xpos = (+x + "px");
    var ypos = (+y + "px");
    move();
  });
  function move(){
    $("#move").animate({
      "top": +ypos, "left": +xpos
      //"top": "50px"   <-- but this works
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

Comment: If you mean drag & drop, you can use the Drag and Drop API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API). But since it's not yet supported by most browsers, you can use the events `click`, `mouseover`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`, and `mousemove`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not passing the xpos and ypos parameters to your move function. Try something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).click(function(e) {
        var x = e.pageX;
        var y = e.pageY;
        var xpos = (+x + "px");
        var ypos = (+y + "px");
        move(xpos, ypos);
      });
      function move(x, y){       //pass in your parameters here
        $("#move").animate({
          "top": x, "left": y
          // "top": "50px"   //<-- but this works
        }, 1000);

      }
    });
```